# I want to add a Schema annotation via Javafx to the package-info.java

Tags: java, xml, schema

So I have a specific Schema annotation I need to be added to the package-info.java. I tried around a few things and searched for an answer online, but couldn't find any that apply to my problem.

packag-info.java:

```
@javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema(
          ...
        )
package my.package.name;
```

XmlSchema I want:

```
<databaseChangeLog
    xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog-ext 
        http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-ext.xsd http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/pro
        http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/pro/liquibase-pro-4.1.xsd http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog 
        http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-4.1.xsd">
</databaseChangeLog>
```

My question is, what has to go inside the `@javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema(...)`, to achieve this schema?

Comment: I think you need jaxb. Search for a tutorial on it. You can use it to generate java classes based on your xml schema.

Comment: @Just another Java programmer For the classes I use Jaxb, but this particular case can't be done with jaxb, at least to my knowledge, that's why I try to do it this way^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone having a similar problem, I found the solution.

The Schema here has two components which have to be set to in your code to generate,

the namespace:

`xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"`

the schemaLocation:

```
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog-ext 
        http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-ext.xsd http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/pro
        http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/pro/liquibase-pro-4.1.xsd http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog 
        http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-4.1.xsd"
```

The `namespace` has to be set inside the `package-info.java` using `javax`

```
@javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema(
            namespace = "http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog",
            elementFormDefault = javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED)
package de.softproject.x4.server.migration.keycloak.changelog_beans;
```

But the `schemaLocation` can't be set here, or at least I haven't found out how. What works is to set it with `jaxb` directly (I am using jaxb as my Java XML Binding Framework, if you're using another, this solution won't apply)

```
JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(ClassToHaveSchema.class);
Marshaller marshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_SCHEMA_LOCATION, 
                    "http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog-ext 
                     http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog- 
                               ext.xsd http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/pro
                     http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/pro/liquibase-pro-4.1.xsd 
                     http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog 
                     http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog- 
                             4.1.xsd");
```

The important part here is the `marshaller.setProperty(Marshallar.JAXB_SCHEMA_LOCATION, ...)`. When you set up your JAXB Marshaller with the class you want to marshall, this will add the `xsi:schemaLocation` you specified and automatically generate the `xmlns:xsi` for you (the standard namespace prefix xsi)

The resulting XML will then have the schema set like this:

```
<ClassToHaveSchema
    xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog-ext 
        http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-ext.xsd http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/pro
        http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/pro/liquibase-pro-4.1.xsd http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog 
        http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-4.1.xsd">
</ClassToHaveSchema>
```

Your SchemaLocation may be shorter or longer than here, it doesn't have to be 6 URIs long, it's in this case though.

You could of course create a class containing this information as constants:

```
public class LiquibaseInfo {

    public static final String NAMESPACE = "http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog";
    public static final String SCHEMA_LOCATION = "http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog-ext http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-ext.xsd http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/pro http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/pro/liquibase-pro-4.1.xsd http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-4.1.xsd";

    private LiquibaseInfo() {}
}
```

And then use the constants in your code, which would make it a little bit more understandable:

```
...
namespace = LiquibaseInfo.NAMESPACE
...

...
marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_SCHEMA_LOCATION, LiquibaseInfo.SCHEMA_LOCATION);
...
```

CAUTION:
When setting the `namespace` inside the package-info this package now is linked to this `namespace`. Meaning, if you for example unmarshall some XML file inside some class in this package, which uses another `namespace`, it will not work, because it expects the set `namespace`. Happend to me, can be fixed easily, by changing up the packages better, but so you don't have to ponder over your code not working.